# JBoss AS7 long startup, strange warnings

Tags: eclipse, jboss, warnings, jboss7.x

I use a JBoss AS7 (7.0.2.Final) server. The startup takes a long time (a couple of minutes) and there are strange warning in the logs:

```
09:51:20,822 WARN  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (pool-2-thread-6) JBAS012100: Got error closing channel JBREM00206: Channel is not open
09:51:20,856 WARN  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (pool-2-thread-1) JBAS012100: Got error closing channel JBREM00206: Channel is not open
09:51:20,863 WARN  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (pool-2-thread-6) JBAS012100: Got error closing channel JBREM00206: Channel is not open
09:51:21,377 WARN  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (pool-2-thread-4) JBAS012100: Got error closing channel JBREM00206: Channel is not open
```

What's wrong?

I removed temporary files (`standalone/data/content` and `standalone/tmp/vfs`) and it helped, but only for a short time (a couple of startups).

**EDIT:** What is more during JBoss startup my browser becomes irresponsive and generally it is hard to work.

**EDIT2:** Answering to the comment written by Rich. I deploy a simple web application with datasource on mysql. There are not many differences between standard JBoss configuration and mine. As far as I remember I added a datasource and a module for mysql. I have this problems during development on my localhost so I'm not sure if I should check other servers in the subnet.

**EDIT3:** It seems to be a problem with eclipse and JBoss together, because when I run a server from command line, the startup process is smooth and there is no warnings.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your application (if there is one?), and whether there are other JBoss instances on the subnet?

Comment: Can you paste the startup log from when you launch the AS7 instance from the command line? Also, do you have the startup issues when you reload the server after disabling the web application? Is the datasource's driver deployed as an application, or configured as a module?

Comment: Can you reproduce this also on AS7.1.1.Final? as 7.0.2 is quite old and has lots of known issues that ware already fixed

Comment: Thanks for comments, guys. I stopped working with JBoss a couple of months ago and now I can't check it. I'll do it when I use that server again.